# AngularJS - Generating dynamic image map

Tags: image, angularjs, imagemap, dynamic-html

I am getting image map from the server and trying to display contents using ng-bind-html. while rendering AngularJS removes **name** attribute from map tag. Therefore user clicks are not affective in map.

[This sample code.](http://plnkr.co/edit/j5ylalmEabQH7GonOB4C?p=preview)

```
      <body ng-app="imgMapExample">
        <div ng-controller="ExController">
         <p ng-bind-html="ImgData"></p>
        </div>
      </body>

 angular.module('imgMapExample', ['ngSanitize'])
    .controller('ExController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

      var imgPath = "http://www.w3schools.com/tags/";
      var imgPlanet =  imgPath + "planets.gif";
      var imgSun =  imgPath + "sun.htm";
      var imgvenus =  imgPath + "venus.htm";
      var imgmercur =  imgPath + "mercur.htm";

      var ImgTag = '<img src="' + imgPlanet + '" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap" />';
      var imgMap = '<map name="planetmap"> <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="Sun" href="' + imgSun + '"> <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="Mercury" href="' + imgmercur + '"> <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" alt="Venus" href="' + imgvenus  + '"> </map>';

      var imgMapTest = '<map name="planetmap"></map>';

      $scope.ImgData =  ImgTag + imgMap;

    }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used `$sce.trustAsHtml(ImgTag + imgMap);` until Angular will update the code not to remove name attribute.

[github - issues 8719](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8719)

[Sample code](http://plnkr.co/edit/R2oKsetegH8WrL1ukaf7?p=preview)